# Multi tenancy UI customization

Tags: angularjs, customization, compass-sass, multi-tenant

I am facing an architectural problem with designing the UI customization solution for a multi tenant application, the application architecture is as follows

Our is a single page application.

We have two servers Server A and Server B

Server A is responsible for serving the HTML and other static assets like css, images etc.

Server B is the backend api server.

Current Front end build process, works on the front end server, on every git commit, we trigger a build process which does the job of compilation of scss to css files.

The bottleneck here is that we need to manually add the custom variables.scss file for every new tenant to be able to generate the tenant specific css.

We want to automate this process such that we can upload a new variables.scss file and have it included in the build process for generating tenant specific css.

So basically looking for ideas on how to achieve this efficiently.

Let me know if further details are required.

**UPDATE**
In our index.html we are dynamically loading tenant specific css file based on the subdomain present in the url.

We use a grunt based build task for sass compilation, here's how it works.

we have a sass folder which contains  main.scss in the root and a tenants folder inside the sass folder which further contains a subfolder for every tenant, each sub folder contains a variables.scss. We have written a grunt task which does the job of dynamically generating the css file for every tenant( by merging main.scss and variables.scss ) in the dist folder.